# how to implement shared preferences in hybrid mobile application using apache cordova

Tags: cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-5.0.0

I am using **cordova** hybrid mobile application. In that application I want to implement shared preferences in the code. I get a response from server also.
How to implement the shared preferences in my application. I get the response through **jquery** and my file extension is **.html**

Comment: could you post some of your code what data you need to store in shared preferences.

Comment: I need to store username and password in shared preferences. Here i have to use the shared preferences under response.status==S :                                    $.get(action, data, function(response) {
   if(response.status == 'S')
   {
   window.location.href= 'sample.html';
   }
   else
   {
   $('#errorDiv').show();
   $('#username').val('');
   $('#password').val('');
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in cordova app you can use local storage for e.g.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('Username',value); //Store your values

window.localStorage.getItem('Username'); //Retrieve your values

window.localStorage.removeItem('Username'); //Remove your values
```

Comment: don't you think storing user credentials in localstorage is unsafe

Comment: @selftaught91 It is depends on your app requirement. in above question he wants to store that information in app using `shared preferences` like user name etc.. so the solution for hybrid app local storage is given as above.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ng Cordova plugin.

```
$cordovaPreferences
```

Methods
store(key, value, dict)
Store the preference of the given dictionary and key.

fetch(key, dict)
Fetch the preference by the given dictionary and key.

remove(key, dict)
Remove the preference by the given dictionary and key.

show()
Show the application preferences. For details on this, check how to show preference pane.

Comment: Link is outdated